# How do I post to wordpress using javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that will need to post content to Wordpress. Is it possible to post to Wordpress using javascript, or will I need to write a Wordpress plugin to do this? If it is possible, are there any libraries you could recommend?

Comment: Have you looked at the 'press this' bookmarklet? http://codex.wordpress.org/Press_This

Comment: I've had a look at that, I'll try and see if I can use it for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform an AJAX request to your server running wordpress ,  I'm not a wordpress user but I assume that WP has a JSON api of some sort.

Comment: As far as I can tell it doesn't actually have a JSON api. It really should, and there are some plugins that do it, but I want to be able to publish to Wordpress without people having to do anything to their own Wordpress installation.

Comment: How about creating the html `form` and elements 'on the fly' and submitting it using javascript?, it would simulate the actual submission of a post, although you would have to check if there are any special tokens to avoid CSRF (as Tomcat Manager does). Also you would have to make request for log-in, you would simulate the requests made by the browser when used by an actual user.